# Android MediaRecorder crashes on button press

Tags: android

First time writing an app for android, when it was just two buttons all was OK so I then decided to try to include the MediaRecorder.
When I press "Start" I get the message "Unfortunately, Button Tutorial has stopped." with "OK".
Could somebody suggest what is wrong and why and then what I need to do to correct it please?
Here is my "MainActivity.java"

```
package example.com;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity 
extends Activity
implements OnClickListener

{
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private String fileName;
    private MediaRecorder myRecorder = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Creating Button variable
        Button Btn_Start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        Button Btn_Stop = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btStop);        

        //Adding Listener to button
        Btn_Start.setOnClickListener(this);
        Btn_Stop.setOnClickListener(this);       
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btStart:
            Log.i("onClick", "btStart BEGIN");
            try {
                startRecording();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("onClick", "btStart END");    
            break;
        case R.id.btStop:
            Log.i("onClick", "btStop BEGIN");
            stopRecording();
            Log.i("onClick", "btStop END"); 
            break;
    }    
}

        private void stopRecording() {
            myRecorder.stop();
    }

        private void startRecording() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
            Log.d(TAG,"void startRecording");
            myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            Log.d(TAG,"new MediaRecorder");
            myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            Log.d(TAG,"setAudioSource");
            myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            Log.d(TAG,"setOutputFormat");
            //myRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audiotest.3gpp";
            myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            myRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
            myRecorder.prepare();
            myRecorder.start();
    }
}
```

And here is the "LogCat"

```
01-27 17:40:34.154: I/onClick(6116): btStart BEGIN
01-27 17:40:34.154: D/(6116): void startRecording
01-27 17:40:34.164: D/(6116): new MediaRecorder
01-27 17:40:34.164: D/AndroidRuntime(6116): Shutting down VM
01-27 17:40:34.164: W/dalvikvm(6116): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417ebba8)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116): Process: example.com, PID: 6116
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116): java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at example.com.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:68)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at example.com.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-27 17:40:34.164: E/AndroidRuntime(6116):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="example.com.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

For info I'm trying to run this on a Google Nexus 7

Many thanks

Comment: can you show your manifest file ?

Comment: Did you declare the proper permissions in your manifest?

Comment: @ amit singh AndroidManifest.xml added to original post.

Comment: @ Martin Cazares I wouldn't know, sorry very new to this. I have read about permissions but seen a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks to all for help with "Permissions", I can confirm that it now records. Time to do more reading I think.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are missing required permissions, try

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

You will also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```